# do something before confirm dialog pops up

Tags: javascript, jquery, confirm

```js
$('.lorem').on('click', function(){
    $(this).hide();
    if(prompt('DO SOMETHING') != null) {console.log('something');}
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class='lorem'>lorem</div>
```

So I firstly want to hide the div and then pop up the confirm dialog. Is it possible?

Comment: Yes throw the prompt in an animation frame `window.requestAnimationFrame(() => {if(prompt('DO SOMETHING') != null) {console.log('something');} }`

Comment: You may have to do a nested animation frame callback as one will run before the next repaint eg: `requestAnimationFrame(() => { /* div is about to be hidden on next paint*/ requestAniamtionFrame(() => { /* div was hidden on last paint */} })`

Comment: [window.requestAnimationFrame()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/window/requestAnimationFrame)

Comment: @JayHarris, don't tell me pls that I need to use entire API to hide a div?

Comment: You are not trying to just hide a div. You are trying to guarantee that your code only runs after the div is hidden. The function I suggested is extremely simple as it only accepts a callback that will fire before the browser paints the screen.

Comment: hide accepts a callback function, for when the animation is complete: http://api.jquery.com/hide/#hide-duration-complete -move your prompt there

Comment: @TiesonT. actually without params, jquery won't animate

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use animation frames to run code before the next paint.

[window.requestAnimationFrame()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/window/requestAnimationFrame)

```
$('.lorem').on('click', function(){
    // The browser will paint async not sync, so the div may still be visible
    // even after this line
    $(this).hide();
    // when the browser is ready to paint the div off screen the callback will fire
    window.requestAnimationFrame(() => { 
        if (prompt('DO SOMETHING') != null) {
            console.log('something');
        }
    });
});
```

note: You may have to do nested animation frames as browsers tend to implement request animation frame differently.

```
requestAnimationFrame(() => requestAnimationFrame(() => {
    ...
}));
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a setTimeout:

```
 document.querySelector('.lorem').addEventListener('click',  () => {
  document.querySelector('.lorem').style.display = "none";
   setTimeout(() => {
     if(prompt("do something") !== null) {
       console.log('do something')
     }
   }, 100)
  })
```

Comment: note that `settimeout` doesn't guarantee to run before the next repaint. In theory JavaScript can run multiple task before deciding to repaint.

Comment: Seems like OP was looking for a simple solution based on the way he reacted to your answer, so I gave him one